# Mount folder to docker container via dockerfile or docker-compose.yml file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers, docker-volume

I need to edit nginx.conf file in /etc/nginx/ folder from a service from within a docker container. Is there a way to do this through Dockerfile or docker-compose.yml file? All the solutions I have come across only mention using docker run command.

Comment: Please share more details. Why not change whatever you want to change, and then use `COPY` to persist these settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well there are multiple ways, I assume you want your docker container to have specific files while running right? then I would recommend use in Dockerfile like this

```
     COPY  nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
```

I would highly suggest copy command because this copy of file will live along with image.

or you can mount this via docker-compose like this

```
services:
  frontend:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/
    container_name: nginx
```